# selecting the 7n item including the first item with css nth-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

with css :nth-child pseudo-selector. how do i select every 7n item including the first one (that is item at 0 index).

For example:

- 1.highlight me
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- 6
- 7.highlight me
- 8
- 9
- 10
- 11
- 12
- 13
- 14.highlight me

i tried :nth-child(7n) but it doesn't match the first item.

Comment: There are **5** items between 1 and 7, and **6** items between 7 and 14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
:nth-child(6n+1) { ... }
```

**[Working Example](http://jsbin.com/uqesud/4)**

Comment: In that case 13th will be highlighted, the range can be adjusted accordingly after fixing li numbering.

Comment: There are 5 items between 1 and 7, and 6 items between 7 and 14.

Comment: Ah I see yeah that's it, the answer served the purpose of the OP then.

Comment: @Kobi: How it is hostile edit? If my edit was wrong, then the OP can refuse it. I just guess that it should be like my edit, nothing else. There is nothing hostile in SO. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @sarwar026 - It is extremely confusing - it introduced an error in the OP's question, which wasn't there before. A comment would be much more appropriate, in my opinion. The OP is not the one who approved it, by the way. (hostile is a poor choice of words)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a mix of two or more styles:

```
:first-child, :nth-child(7n) {
  .
  .
  .
}
```

This would do it!